# Bad Substition how to force /bin/bash as a shell?

Tags: bash

I have a script that is getting run by a third party environment which is running the script with "/bin/sh".

Is there a way from within the script that I can force bash to be used instead, for example by wrapping the commands in `bash <<EOF  ... EOF`, like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

bash <<EOF
IMPORTS=$(find /home/snowch -type f -name .project)

for item in ${IMPORTS[*]};
do
   IMPORT="$(dirname $item)/"
   echo $IMPORT
done
EOF
```

Comment: make sure you quote the terminator: `bash <<'EOF'`

Comment: A bash script is not necessarily a valid POSIX shell script. Either convert your script to be POSIX shell compatible (which would be the best way IMO) or invoke it with the bash interpreter. The shebang line should do its job, that's what it's for. Run the script, don't invoke it with a wrong interpreter.

Comment: @Marco a user or an application might ignore the shebang by explicitly stating the shell to use. `/bin/sh` is not guaranteed to be the POSIX shell on every POSIX compliant platform.

Comment: @jlliagre That's why I suggested to run the script (in that case the interpreter might be unknown) instead of using `/bin/sh` as interpreter (which only works if the script language is bourne shell compatible).

Comment: @marco My understanding is the script is run by a third party tool the OP cannot change/adapt.

Comment: @jlliagre Your understanding is correct, I can't change the interpreter running the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use this syntax which doesn't require the `$` to be escaped unlike your here document attempt.

```
#!/bin/bash

bash -c '
IMPORTS=$(find /tmp/foo -type f -name .project)

for item in ${IMPORTS[*]};
do
   IMPORT="$(dirname $item)/"
   echo $IMPORT
done
'
```

Here is a more robust way (thanks to Gilles' comment suggesting it), that has the advantage to allow single quotes to be present in the embedded script:

```
#!/bin/bash

bash <<"%EOF%"
IMPORTS=$(find /tmp/foo -type f -name .project)

for item in ${IMPORTS[*]};
do
   IMPORT="$(dirname $item)/"
   echo $IMPORT
done
%EOF%
```

Note: there is no way to prevent someone to use a different shell than the one specified with the shebang. Writing a portable script (i.e. POSIX) script doesn't guarantee it will work with `/bin/sh` on every platform as the sandard doesn't mandate the POSIX shell to use this path.

Comment: But then you can't comfortably use `'` inside the bash snippet. A quoted here-document works better.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for your better approach, answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

You could check from within the script if `bash` is being used.  If not, replace the current shell with `bash`.  If that fails, abort the script.

```
[ -z $BASH ] && { exec bash "$0" "$@" || exit; }
```

This would ensure that the script can only be executed using `bash`.  (You might want to replace the complete path to `bash` in the command above.)

Note that as pointed by [@Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) and as noted in the following comment, this should be the first line in the script.

Comment: Yes, but if there were any definitions of shell variables above that point, they will not be available after the `exec`. For a self-contained script, you'd just start with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: Yes, I should have added that this ought to be the _first line_ in the script.

Comment: If `/bin/sh` is actually bash then `$BASH` will have a value. So using `-z` isn't sufficient.

Comment: @bahamat Unless I'm missing something, if `/bin/sh` is actually `bash` chances are that there won't be any issue in using bash specific constructs.

Comment: @devnull: `bash` has some behavioral differences when invoked as `sh`. I guess it really depends on whether or not *that* makes a difference.